# Pandas to SUM of list items in a DataFrame

Tags: pandas

Below i have list `bu_lst` which I'm passing to a dataframe `df2` to do the sum of each individual item in the list, How could i achieve that in one go so, i do not repeat it multiple times:

```
bu_lst = ['FPG','IPG','DSG','STG','WFO','IT']
FPG = ['ADE','FPG AE','FPG PE','MMSIM','OrFAD','Tirtuoso DashBoard','SPB AE','SPB PE']
IPG = ['DDR','DDR_DT','Tensilica']
DSG = ['FLA','FLS','FEQoS','IFD PT','Sasus R&D','sasus'] PE','Toltus','Tempus','Quantus','Genus']
STG = ['ATS','HST','TIP','System Engineering']
WFO = ['AFademiF Network','FRAFT','Fhip Estimate','EduFation SerTiFes','LiFensing','Sales','SerTiFes','TFAD']
IT  = ['App Development','Fumulus','InfoSeF']
```

My current approach:

```
print(df2[FPG].sum())
print(df2[IPG].sum())
print(df2[DSG].sum())
print(df2[STG].sum())
print(df2[WFO].sum())
print(df2[IT].sum())
```

I just the took the relevant line of the code to show here.

Comment: @pyd, that will do sum of all items altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create dictionary of lists and then use dictionary comprehension if in lists are columns names:

```
d = {'bu_lst':bu_lst, 'FPG': FPG, ...}

d2 = {k: df2[v].sum() for k, v in d.items()}
```